# Adding Date in the form of string to an Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to display 20 days from now, in the format of `Mon, Feb 25th 2012`. i think i will have to take the system time of the iPhone, and make it appear in the following format. I need to add all these 20 dates in an array afterwards.

I only coded the creating the Array part, and have no clue how to do this. Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formatter route is all very well, but why do you want to store dates as strings in an array?

Dates really should be stored as `NSDate`s right up until the moment they need to be displayed, and then you can run them through a formatter. An `NSDate` is an object, and can be stored quite easily in an NSArray.

But, seriously, ask yourself why you need 20 days? What are you going to do with them. there are other ways of doing this. If you need the 20 days for displaying in a UITableView, just store the `NSDate`s and use a formatter to turn the date into strings when creating the cells.

If you want to be able to refer to a date x days in the future based on a start date, don't generate them all at once, store the start date, calculate the offset you want and then generate the new date on the fly and format it before displaying it. Actually, this method would work for tables as well, you could lazily create the dates, and cache them while the app was running. A bit more work, but far more scaleable than a static NSArray of NSStrings.

There seem to be a few of these types of questions turning up where somebody asks a question, and gets a string of answers which are factually correct, but not really trying to solve the spirit of the question.

Yes - generate the dates, turn them into strings using an NSDateFormatter and store them in an array.

Or, think about why you want 20 consecutive dates, and how you are going to be using them, and use a more appropriate storage / display workflow.

Comment: +1 for encouraging looking for the best solution / approach and not necessarily what the original poster asks for.

Answer (score 2):

Adding days should be done as calendric calculations.

```
NSDate *initialDate = ...;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"EEE, MMM dd yyyy"];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
for ( int i = 1; i <=20; i++ ) {
    [c setDay: i];
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents: c toDate: initialDate options: 0];
    NSLog(@"+ %d days = %@", i, [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date]);
}
[calendar release];
[c release];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility lies in NSDateFormatter and stringFromDate

for the 20th date:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *newDate = [[currentDate] dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600 * 24 * 20];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, MMM dd yyyy";

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: newDate];
```

Edit: you might do better to follow Abizern and Costique's answers/suggestions depending upon your specific requirements.

Comment: This is for current date, but how do i get it for like 10 days from now ? if today is THU, JUN 2012, I need another 9 like that.. FRI, JUN 2012 etc.

Comment: @Illep - then it would be dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600 * 24 * 10

Comment: So, without adding a loop, can you print the 1st 10 or 20 records ? If i NSLog, will all 20 records display ?

Comment: -1 Really? Adding seconds to a date to get to the next day?. What happens if there is a Daylight Savings Time change during the 20 days? You'll either have the same day twice, or you'll skip a day.

Comment: @Abizern -- Then get in bed with NSCalendar.  It's a tradeoff between accuracy and simplicity.

Comment: When programming with dates - accuracy wins every time. Look at @Costique 's answer. It's not much longer, or complicated, and includes the loop to generate the days. Not much of a trade off there.